# Make Pandas groupby apply behave like transform?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, transform, apply

**Is there a way to apply a function that return iterables of the same lengths as the groups, and "transform" the results as a new column?**

I have some time series data of serveral groups that are interweaved.
For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
iris_data = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df = iris_data.head(5).copy()
df = pd.concat([df, iris_data.iloc[50:55]])
df = pd.concat([df, iris_data.iloc[100:105]])
df = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=0).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.drop(columns=["sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width"])
df.index = pd.date_range("2020/12/16", periods=15)
df
```

```
   sepal_length species
2020-12-16  4.9 setosa
2020-12-17  6.4 versicolor
2020-12-18  5.5 versicolor
2020-12-19  6.5 versicolor
2020-12-20  6.5 virginica
2020-12-21  5.0 setosa
2020-12-22  4.7 setosa
2020-12-23  6.3 virginica
2020-12-24  6.3 virginica
2020-12-25  6.9 versicolor
2020-12-26  5.8 virginica
2020-12-27  4.6 setosa
2020-12-28  5.1 setosa
2020-12-29  7.0 versicolor
2020-12-30  7.1 virginica
```

I want to apply some time-dependent logic to each group (in this case, each species), and append the results as a new column.

For example, if I want to calculate an "is new-high" indicator in each series: (again THIS IS NOT THE POINT OF THE QUESTION, just an example of time-dependent calculations)

```
def is_new_high(group):
    """
    This function simulates some order-dependent calculations as an illustration.
    It labels True if the current sepal_length is longer than the previous one in the same species.
    
    This probably can be achieved without groupby and apply, but that is not the point here.
    """
    group_res = [False] * len(group)
    running_max = 0
    for i, (row_idx, row) in enumerate(group.iterrows()):
        if row.sepal_length > running_max:
            running_max = row.sepal_length
            group_res[i] = True
    return(group_res)
```

which when applied to the df

```
grouped_results = df.groupby(df.species).apply(is_new_high)
grouped_results
```

yields a Series that indicates whether an observation is a new-high in that species:

```
species
setosa         [True, True, False, False, True]
versicolor      [True, False, True, True, True]
virginica     [True, False, False, False, True]
dtype: object
```

With a little bit of (inefficient) Pandas trickery (see below), this can be merged back into the original df:

```
   sepal_length species     new_high
2020-12-16  4.9 setosa      True
2020-12-17  6.4 versicolor  True
2020-12-18  5.5 versicolor  False
2020-12-19  6.5 versicolor  True
2020-12-20  6.5 virginica   True
2020-12-21  5.0 setosa      True
2020-12-22  4.7 setosa      False
2020-12-23  6.3 virginica   False
2020-12-24  6.3 virginica   False
2020-12-25  6.9 versicolor  True
2020-12-26  5.8 virginica   False
2020-12-27  4.6 setosa      False
2020-12-28  5.1 setosa      True
2020-12-29  7.0 versicolor  True
2020-12-30  7.1 virginica   True
```

Since the function applied is time- or order-dependent, I cannot think of a way to turn it into a Pandas "transform" function that acts on columns and not on a group (i.e., DataFrame). So it seems I'm stuck with using apply that returns a vector for each group.

My question is the following: **Is there a way to apply a function that return iterables of the same lengths as the groups, and "transform" the results as a new column**, to achieve the same result as in my example?

---

Here's the inefficient and ad-hoc way I did it:

```
def is_new_high(group):
    group_res = [(idx, False) for idx in group.index]
    temp = 0
    for i, (row_idx, row) in enumerate(group.iterrows()):
        if row.sepal_length > temp:
            temp = row.sepal_length
            group_res[i] = (row_idx, True)
    return(group_res)

grouped_results_exploded = grouped_results.explode()
res = pd.DataFrame(grouped_results_exploded.tolist(), index=grouped_results_exploded.index,)
res.columns=['timestamp', 'new_high']
res = res.reset_index().set_index("timestamp")
df.join(res, rsuffix="_groupby")
```

Comment: So does your calculation depends on multiple columns or a single column?

Comment: Hi Dani, the calculation does depend on multiple columns. 
I'm sorry the example wasn't quite clear on that, but I didn't want the logic of the function applied to each group obfuscate what I am trying to ask -- a "hybrid" of transform and apply -- which is a bit more general.